# Android Onclick not working with the example

Tags: android, event-handling

I'm new with android try to run the application below.
package theoiziruam.clicker.
Only the Onclick event for the btnClick is working instead no chance to set textfield to 0 with the btnReset.
No errors when I'm compiling, no idea...very curios to know what's the issue.
Can you help me?

```
package theoiziruam.clicker;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btnClick;
Button btnReset;
TextView txtCount;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnClick=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonClick);
    btnReset=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonClick);
    txtCount=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCount);

    btnReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(0));


        }
    });

    btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String countValue=txtCount.getText().toString();
            int intCountValue= Integer.parseInt(countValue);
            intCountValue++;
            txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(intCountValue));
            if (intCountValue>10) { }

        }
    });

    }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
btnClick=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonClick);
btnReset=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonClick);
```

Your buttons are pointing to the same thing.